# How do I use my secondary Armaments?

Tags: world-of-warships

When I look at my ship it says it has secondary armaments that look to be pretty damaging while my main batteries are reloading.

to use them the "help" screen said to do ctrl+click on your target, but this didn't do anything at all.

How do I fire my secondary armaments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secondary batteries fire automatically, but have a much shorter range than your main batteries (Lower tier ships generally require the target to be within about three to four km. Some of the higher tier battleships go up to 7 km). Ctrl-click will designate the target for your secondaries to fire on.

Comment: ctrl is free mouse and when clicking on an enemy with it, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Ctrl-click marks which target you want the secondaries to fire at. You still need to be within secondary range for them to actually start shooting.

Comment: Do you click the target in the 3D view, or on the minimap?

Comment: @SimonW You click on the 3D view

Comment: Thanks :) Figured it out now. It's not obvious at lower tiers because you don't have enough secondary armament to matter...